# Magento 2 - How to do get the product attribute code and value associated with product using product id?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

Hi i want to show the products attribute code and it's value using the product id.

How can i do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to get all product attributes of that product id?

Comment: you can have attribute set of the product, you can get all attributes of that attribute set.

Comment: @RonakChauhan Can you please explain me how can i get it from the product id. I want to get the attributes with it's value in my template file.

Comment: If you have product object then you have all its data, so just use foreach() loop and print data in phtml

Comment: And if you want a attribute information then just use attribute set id and get all its attribute

Comment: I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this,

```
namespace NameSpace\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    array $data = []
)
{
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}

public function getProductById($id)
{
    return $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
}

public function getProductBySku($sku)
{
    return $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
}
}
```

and in your phtml.

```
$id = YOUR_PRODUCT_ID;
$product = $block->getProductById($id); // load product bi ID
$attributes = $product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) { 
   echo $attribute->getAttributeCode(); echo '<br />';
   echo $attribute->getStoreLabel(); echo '<br />';
   echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel(); echo '<br />';    
   echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(); echo '<br />';

// you might not get value for all attributes
   echo $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product); echo '<br />';    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All other answer are helpful but i want to get the attribute value with multi select also. so i used the

```
$product->getResource()->getAttribute($code)->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

May it help to some one, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the attribute type.

```
 //to get all the attributes of the product by id
    $id = 1; //your Product id
    $data = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id)->getData();
    var_dump($data);

    // also you can get the attribute value dpendong on the attribute type
    //for example you have text field Attribute called(test) to get it's value
    echo  $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id)->getTest();

    //to get a value of select/multi-select Attribute called(test) will return as array
    var_dump($this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id)->getAttributeText('test'));
```

Comment: Use product factory to load the product with DI : \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory : $productFactory->create()->load($id);